# PHP : ERROR Fault occurred in processing, detail provided

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I created a PHP soap client for integrating a payment gateway in my website .  but getting *ERROR Fault occurred in processing, detail provided* .  when running my code

**SOAP request xml**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:req="http://olp.bank.com/payement/service/olppaymentmanager/req">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <req:initiatePaymentDetailsReq>
         <olpIdAlias>****</olpIdAlias>
         <merchantId>****</merchantId>
         <merchantRefNum>897465161</merchantRefNum>
         <paymentAmount>100</paymentAmount>
         <paymentCurrency>USD</paymentCurrency>
         <dynamicMerchantLandingURL></dynamicMerchantLandingURL>
         <dynamicMerchantFailureURL></dynamicMerchantFailureURL>
      </req:initiatePaymentDetailsReq>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**php code**

```
include 'initiatePaymentDetailsReq.php';

$wsdl = dirname(__FILE__).'/librb/RB_OLP_INITIATE_PAYMENT.wsdl';

$endpoint       = 'https://b2b.bank.com/soap?service=RB_OLP_INITIATE_PAYMENT';
$local_cert = dirname(__FILE__)."/key1.pem";
$passphrase = "*****";
$options = array(
    'location'      => $endpoint,
    'keep_alive'    => true,
    'trace'         => true,
    'local_cert'    => $local_cert,
    'passphrase'    => $passphrase,
    'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'exceptions' => 0

);

try{

        $client = new SoapClient($wsdl,$options); 

    } catch (SoapFault $E) { 
        echo $E->getMessage();
    }
    if ($client) {                                
$in=new StdClass();


$in->olpIdAlias='****';
      $in->merchantId='***';
        $in->merchantRefNum='6484561464';
          $in->paymentAmount='100';
            $in->paymentCurrency='USD';
                $in->dynamicMerchantLandingURL='';
                    $in->dynamicMerchantFailureURL='';


try{
               $response = $client->executeRB_OLP_INITIATE_PAYMENT($in);
                      var_dump($response);
}catch(Exception $ex) {
    die($ex->getMessage());
}


}
```

can anybody help me to find what's the error in my code ..?

Comment: You have a trailing `'` at the end of your `if ($client) {`-row. Copy/paste error?

Comment: sorry. I didn't get @magnus Eriksson.

Comment: You didn't get what?

Comment: i couldn't understand what you said.? :( @Magnus Eriksson

Comment: Look at the row containing `if ($client) {`. At the end of that row, you have a `'`-character a bunch of spaces to the right. Is it a copy/paste error or is that in your actual code? If it is in your code, this would most definitely give you an error.

Comment: its a copy past mistake not in my actual code. @Magnus Eriksson